# QGIS grid not displaying

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, grids-graticules

I'm making a world map in QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas. The data came from Natural Earth using the WGS84 CRS, however I want to use a Robinson projection for my map. I reprojected the data, by clicking 'save as' and selecting World_Robinson for the output layer.

When I try to display a grid however, nothing happens. If the shapefile is in the original WGS84 I can get the grid to display in the composer, however it doesn't work with the grid CRS set to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) and the data has been reprojected into World_Robinson.

When I set the grid CRS to ESRI:54030, for World_Robinson, this happens.

How can I proceed?

I'm running MacOS El Capitan.

This is my first time using QGIS.

Edit: here is the grid with WGS84.

[image: Grid]

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: The combination of EPSG:54030 (in meters) with a grid interval of 5 meters for the whole world certainly doesn't make sense. Show us settings you are using for your desired WGS84 grid.

Comment: @underdark I'm trying to follow this guide: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html which suggests that I can have my data projected in Robinson, but use WGS84 for the grid. 5 was the suggested interval in that tutorial. Here are the settings I'm trying to use for the graticule. Ideally I'd like to have the unites in degrees.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the **interval unit** to **CRS units** instead of map units because map units are meters if your map is projected to EPSG:54030.

Comment: OK thank you so much for your help, and for being so patient. When I try to do this however, the only options that are visible are map units, millimeters, and centimeters. Is there something I need to do to enable selecting CRS units? I've attached a screenshot above.

Comment: Update: I got it to work! The only issue is that the grid only appears when I am zoomed in on the map. So for example, if I want to display only Japan, or only Europe, the grid lines will appear. If I zoom out however, to display the whole world, and there is white space around the map, the grid lines will not show up. Do you know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: When the map is small scale, the grid will work. If I move the map content in the print composer the grid will move with it. If however, I try to make a large scale map, and display the entire oval shape of the robinson projection, the map becomes detached from the grid, or the grid simply disappears.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oBBe1upnC36yrPGiK0CG9c2u6eXxOTyFR6FaAg-iu2Y/edit?usp=sharing The first is the small scale map, the second the large scale (156848459) where the grid has become detached, and the third where a new and identical grid is not visible from the start.

Comment: @Ben seems like this should be a bug report